# Blur/Unblur function as a protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, blur, uivisualeffectview

I have created **Blurable** protocol with extension that have **blur** function.

```
protocol Blurable {}

extension Blurable where Self: UIView {

    func blur(with effect:  UIBlurEffectStyle) {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: effect)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

        blurEffectView.frame = bounds
        addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
}
```

Now I want to add **unblur** function.
If it would be a class I would make **blurEffectView** as a class property and create **unblur** function like this:

```
func unblur() {
    blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview
}
```

Since protocol extensions don't allow for stored properties what is correct solution to this problem?

Comment: using computed property it seems not possible you must have to define var somewhere else. why don't you make a Blurable a class and extend every your custom views with  Blurable

Comment: I can do this but it would be more comfortable and precisely for me to do this as a protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep variable in protocol declaration.

```
protocol Blurable: class {
    var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView? { set get }

    func applyBlur(with effect: UIBlurEffectStyle)
    func removeBlur() 
}

private var xoAssociationKey: UInt8 = 0

extension Blurable where Self: UIView {

    // If you want to avoid adding "blurEffectView" to each UIView class, 
    // you can do it this way
    var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKey) as? UIVisualEffectView
        }

        set(newBlurEffectView) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKey, newBlurEffectView, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

    func applyBlur(with effect: UIBlurEffectStyle) {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: effect)
        blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

        blurEffectView?.frame = bounds

        if let blurEffectView = blurEffectView { addSubview(blurEffectView) }
    }

    func removeBlur() {
        if let blurEffectView = blurEffectView {
            blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        blurEffectView = nil
    }
}
```

This should works. You can keep a blurEffectView as non-optional variable but this solution is more safe and effective in future changes because you can check programatically if blur is applied.

```
var someView = SomeView()

if let _ = someView.blurEffectView {
    print("YEAP")
} else {
    print("NOPE")
}
```

Comment: Just a general note, if you constrain your protocol to classes, you don't need the mutating modifier. ```e.g. protocol Blurable: class {
    var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView? { set get }

    func applyBlur(with effect: UIBlurEffectStyle)
    func removeBlur()
}```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thx guys.

Answer (score 0):

I used this -

```
extension UIView {
    func blur() {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }

    func unBlur() {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview is UIVisualEffectView {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also add a tag and remove the view by checking its tag but I felt this is a better option. Extension is also available [here](https://gist.github.com/NikhilManapure/38ee6932ccea4fea1296782f905768fe).